# AngularJS $cookies.get() always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I'm using AngularJS 1.4.0 and the `$cookies` service.  The following code will always print out an empty object:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("user-cookies-service", []);

    app.service('UserCookiesService', ["$cookies", function($cookies) {
        $cookies.put("Hello", "World");
        console.log($cookies.getAll());
    }]);
})();
```

I've tried:

- Using AngulerJS 1.3.15 and `$cookieStore` where cookies don't persist when the browser is refreshed (but it at least created the cookies).
- Adding an expiry date.
- Making sure Cookies are enabled in my browser (Chrome).
- Trying plain old JS, which still doesn't work.

I haven't been able to find a similar issue anywhere.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there is any error in console?

Comment: No. It doesn't work with plain old JS either.  Cookies are enabled in my browser if that makes a difference.

Comment: Figured it out, apparently you have to launch chrome with a certain flag to allow cookies on local files. I'm writing up an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this problem...

By default, Chrome doesn't allow cookies for local files.  You have to run it with the `--enable-file-cookies` flag.

Make sure Chrome is closed and open the Windows Command Prompt/Terminal and run the following command:

```
<path-to-chrome>/chrome.exe --enable-file-cookies
```

This will allow you to put/get cookies locally.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

A little late but for anyone having the same issue. I had a similar problem. You have to make sure you are passing the correct options as the third parameter. In my case the path was not being set. Angular uses your `<base>` tag to set the path. If that is not available for whatever reason, it will not set the cookie.

try this

```
$cookies.put('secret', 'I cant tell you' {
   expires: new Date(date),
   path: '/'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe cookies should be available after refresh, try to log it in opposite way

```
console.log($cookies.getAll());
$cookies.put("Hello", "World");
```

first load: {}, second load: {"Hello": "World"}

in angular 1.3, use $cookies.Hello = "world"; to set cookie

Comment: Thanks, but see my own answer. I stumbled upon it when messing around with the Chome developer's console.