# Get jquery cookie using angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cookies

I'm using jquery.cookie v1.4.1 to set a cookie like this

```
$.cookie('userCookie', $("#user").val());
```

Where  $("#user").val() is returning something like 'username'

Then in an angular app, am trying to retrieve this cookie using

```
var userCookie = $cookies.get('userCookie');
```

But is not working, I'm getting:

```
var userCookie = undefined
```

I'm using AngularJS v1.4.8 with corresponding ngCookies

Any help would be nice....

Comment: Are  cookie path or domain different?

Comment: Yes path are different! It matters!?

Comment: it does if path is set in cookie

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) I got it to work.

It happens that I was setting the cookie for a specific path, let say '/domain/somepath' and then I was trying to retrieve it from '/domain/someotherpath', where the cookie was not available.

I fix it specifying the path on the cookie to all my domain like this:

```
 $.cookie('userCookie',$("#user").val(), { path: '/' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use angular to store your cookies?

```
$cookies.put('userCookie', $("#user").val());
```

Btw: its horrible if you use JQuery like this inside your Angular App.

```
$cookies.get('userCookie');
```

Your problem maybe: the cookie will be created BEFORE your DOM-Element is even rendered on the page. Try $.cookie('userCookie', 'test123'); , this should work pretty sure (with angular 100%).

How to fix this? First of all, DONT USE JQUERY LIKE THIS IF YOU HAVE ANGULAR!!!

```
<input ng-model="username"></input>

$cookies.put('userCookie', $scope.username);
```

Comment: I'm not storing the cookie with jquery in my angular app. The cookie is stored by other site in which I don't use angular, I'm just trying to retrieve it in my angular app...

Comment: Oh, are you sure it's stored in cookies and the name is correct? Other problems: not injected ngCookies and such things, but you would get some exceptions if this happens.

Comment: I'm checking the cookies in chrome and it's correctly stored, and I got no error of injection in the service I'm getting the cookie...

Comment: Hmm..other thing I found is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512473/angularjs-cookies-get-always-returns-undefined. If not, I really don't know whats going on in your application.

Comment: Using $cookies.put('userCookie', 'somename'); effectively sets the cookie and allows me to retrieve it, however I don't have Angular available in the site where I need to store the cookie, does setting the cookie with JQuery won't make it available on angular?

Comment: It's possible that you have to implement a timeout, because jquery runs in a other lifecycle. try $timeout(function(){$cookies.get('userCookie');});. don't forget to inject $timeout. So after the digest-cycle, the method inside of $timeout will be executed. Give it a try