# Why angular 1.6.6v $cookies does not perform read or write operations?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am new in **Angular**. Start working on a test project. i want to store user authentication in cookies. i have tried my best to do it but it will give me undefined error, whenever i tried to retrieve my value, neither confirm about store value, cannot figure out what is wrong? i did work step by step and read many answers on **stackoverflow**. Thanks.

> I have also enable chrome cookies to read and write data [image]

using Angular 1.6.6

```js
angular.module('LoginCtrl', ["ngCookies"])
    .controller('LoginController', function($rootScope, $location, $scope, 
    $http, $cookies)
 {

  $scope.loginformData = {};
  $scope.loginmessage='';
  $scope.errorlogin=false;
  $scope.loginUser = function()
  {
   Login.login($scope.loginformData)
   .then(function(data)
   {
    $scope.loginmessage = data;
    if(data!=='Wrong Email Or Password!')
    {
     $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
     var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
     console.log(favoriteCookie); // return undefined
    }
    else
    {
     $scope.errorlogin = true;
     console.log('Error');    
    }
   });
        };
  

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<base href="/index.html"/>
<div ng-app="LoginCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="LoginController">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS $cookies.get() always returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512473/angularjs-cookies-get-always-returns-undefined)

Comment: Same this problem was faced angular 1.6.2.
Link: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14935

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a detailed analysis of **angular-cookies.js**, when i was debug line by line. I have see **cookiePath** using console.log(). Actually the cookiepath was not assigned a right value.

```
  var cookiePath = $browser.baseHref();
  console.log(cookiePath); // return /index.html
```

*That is invalid path, that was the reason unable to store cookies, the path should be root of my project /*

this wrong path is generated from my index file, where i was set base tag with "/index.html"

```
<base href="/index.html">
```

then i have changed base tag with root, and it work.

```
<base href="/">
```

Now! it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$cookies.putObject('myFavoritec',  'oatmeal');` with the versions above angular 1.4

same goes for getting the information.

```
`$cookies.getObject('myFavoritec');
```

Comment: still undefined