# $cookies.get() gives undefined although document.cookie contains the value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, safari, mobile-safari

In the following code, `xsrfCookie` is *sometimes* undefined. I've measured it at about 20% of the calls.

This only seems to happen in MacOS Safari and on iOS in Safari en Chrome. I am using Angular 1.5.6.

```js
$http.get('some_url')
  .success(function() {
    var xsrfCookie = $cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN');
  });
```

Setting a breakpoint before or after xsrfCookie and logging `document.cookie` or even `$cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')` consistently shows the expected XSRF token.

I can only imagine this has something to do with the XSRF token from the GET being set asynchronously, in parallel to the success function, but I can't find anything in the `angular.get()` code that would suggest this.

Is there anyone who has run into this issue?

Comment: on your first request, the xsrf cookie will never exist. But after that, it would exist normally as it would retuned with the response of this req and further requests in the future

Comment: try putting a timeout for a second when reading it

Comment: @Mouneer Thank you, this is why I'm doing the GET, to create an XSRF token. After this `then` I would do a POST that needs the XSRF token.

Comment: @Mudassar I will try that, but I wonder why this would be needed.

Comment: @mdworld Sorry my bad, I didn't read your code well. Another possible reason: You are using two domains for the same api. for example, sometimes you use localhost and sometimes you use your ip address like 192.168.1.100. So the cookie set on one domain will not be accessible for the another

Comment: Also did you checked this question and its answers?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512473/angularjs-cookies-get-always-returns-undefined

Comment: To be complete: I'm using the same domain for the entire chain. It does seem to have to do with timings, and I got the suggestion this might have to do with how the digest cycle is handled in Safari. I have now set a breakpoint in the current situation like this:
    right after the line with `var xsrfCookie` and when I run  `console.log(xsrfCookie, $cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'))` in the dev console the (pseudo) result is `undefined expectedCookieValue`

Comment: Wrapping the `$cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')` in a `$timeout` of 1ms works. It does not explain why this happens, as this is delegated to a service so it should not involve the digest cycle.

Comment: When I replace `$cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')` by `document.cookie` the same behavior occurs: it is empty at the start of the success callback and set after a 1ms timeout. So it does not seem that $cookies is the problem although it still might be AngularJS + document.cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I have solved this by wrapping the retrieval of the cookie in a timeout:

```
$http.get('some_url')
  .success(function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      var xsrfCookie = $cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN');
    }, 1);
  });
```

Unfortunately, I've not been able to find why this would be needed (expect that it might have something to do with the AngularJS 1.5 digest cycle) but I did found out some other things:

- The original problem only occurs in Safari on iOS and MacOS, and only some of the time. Depending on the environment (intranet, internet) but also varying from day to day, I had sometimes a 100% failure rate and it would sometimes be as low as 10%.
- If I log `document.cookie` as the first thing in the success callback, it is also empty (again only in Safari and only sometimes)
- It might be that `$timeout` is only triggered after the digest is finished and even `$timeout` without the milliseconds param would work
- There are hooks like `onInit` that would only run after the digest cycle is complete, but this call is several service calls deep and I do not understand how this would be involved.